# Kill the [identification] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

A very typical meta tag: [identification](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/identification) for all kinds of "identify this for me" questions.

Most of these are barely useful and can probably be closed and deleted while cleaning up the tag.

Comment: I would add many of these are duplicates, or could be merged into the 'canonical' "How do I identify hardware?" question.

Answer (score 1):

Done. I pruned out any guessing game type questions along the way.